# Working with Asp.net GridView without DataBinding

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Is it possible to populate asp.net GridView with data and operate on those data without dataBinding, as it is possible with Winforms [DataGridView](http://www.windowsclient.net/Samples/Go%20To%20Market/DataGridView/DataGridView%20FAQ.doc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the data source to a datatable that you can build up in code with whatever you like.

```
 var table = new DataTable();
 table.Columns.Add("Column1");
 table.Columns.Add("Column2");

var row = table.NewRow();
row["Column1"] = "test";
row["Column2"] = "test2";

table.Rows.Add(row);

GridView.DataSource = table;
GridView.DataBind();
```

You can also set a gridview's data source with a list:

```
var yourList = new List<YourRowStuff>();
```

get the list from a database query or build it up manually in code....

```
GridView.DataSource = yourList;
GridView.DataBind();
```

Comment: Isn't this databinding?       this.GridView1.DataSource = ((DataTable)Session["myDatatable"]).DefaultView;
this.GridView1.DataBind();

Comment: This is also databinding. Me.GridView1.DataSource = userinfos
Me.GridView1.DataBind()

Comment: All unbound means to me is that the grid is not operating against a DB for me (insert, update, delete,etc).. I control that not the grid. In the above scenario's I control the grid which is the same in the winforms world to me....

Comment: links have broke

Comment: @user7733611 Updated answer without links. :-)