# Generating repeated HTML code without a Repeater

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

How do I duplicate a block of html at the click of a button (for example, add a new row to a non-ASP table)?

My first thought was to use an ASP Repeater. However Repeaters are designed to be databound. While there are some [workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853461/working-with-asp-net-gridview-without-databinding) to using a Repeater to repeat code that isn't databound, this seems like the wrong way to go about it.

ASP.NET has to have a recommended way to do this. I don't think one has to resort to AJAX for this (cue the laser-focus of your responses to be on AJAX...).

I made a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rfsuzdeu/) to visualize the problem, although I'm not necessarily asking for a JS solution:

example html:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Col1</th>
    <th>Col2</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
      <td><button>Button</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button>Add Row</button>
```

Comment: Use Dynamic Controls or User Controls.

Comment: "I don't think one has to resort to AJAX for this (cue the laser-focus of your responses to be on AJAX...)." Wha??

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using databound controls?

Comment: @SeaCharp Because I'm not binding it to any data. Its just some empty controls.

Comment: What will you do with the textbox data when the form is submitted?

Comment: Store the data to a db.

Answer (score -1):

You can duplicate the row by clicking the button. For this you need to assign Id to Row, and then get this row by Id in Javascript function being called in onclick attribute of button. after getting this you can append the html of this row to lastly added row in table. In this way you can add multiple rows by multiple clicks of button. Hopefully this will help you!